# C++ Angles between a vector and a point

Tags: c++, vector, angle

I got 2 points `own=(x, y, z)` and `en=(x, y, z)` which represents my own position in the world and some other player position. the other player also got `pitch` (from 90 degrees to -90) and `yaw` (0 to 360). I want to calculate the angles between the other player look and my own position.

In 2D, alpha is what I'm trying to calculate:

[image]

```
int main()
{
    float own_x = 1, own_y = 1, own_z = 1;
    float en_x = 10, en_y = 1, en_z = 10;
    float pi = 3.14159265;
    float pitch = 0.f * (pi / 180), yaw = 45.f * (pi / 180);
    float x = sin(yaw) * cos(pitch);
    float y = sin(pitch);
    float z = cos(pitch) * cos(yaw);
    float vec_length = sqrt(pow(en_x - own_x, 2) + pow(en_y - own_y, 2) + pow(en_y - own_y, 2));
    x /= vec_length;
    y /= vec_length;
    z /= vec_length;
    float cos_t = ((en_x - own_x)*x + (en_y - own_y)*y + (en_z - own_z)*z) / sqrt(pow(en_x - own_x, 2) + pow(en_y - own_y, 2) + pow(en_y - own_y, 2));
    float arc = acos(cos_t) * (180 / pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem/question?

Comment: It doesn't give the right angel (which is 180 in this example)

Comment: So debug your code?

Comment: in calculation of cos_t, you use: pow(en_y - own_y, 2) twice (in the division). I think the last statement should be: pow(en_z - own_z, 2). Same problem with calculating vec_length

Comment: Btw. how do you know it should be 180? Please provide some explaination. Maybe your assumptions are incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

1. you divide twice with the length of `en-own`: You should remove
   `vec_length`, and `xyz /= vec_length`.
2. your division at `cos_t` is buggy, you use `_y` twice in the
   expression instead of `_y` and `_z`

Note: instead of pow(x, 2), use x*x, it is faster usually (compilers may not optimize pow(x, 2) to x*x).

Comment: mmm got cos > 1 now it's probably not the only problem

Comment: for your example, if I remove the extra division, I got `cos_t=0.157`. Can you give an example where you got `cos_t>1`?

Comment: In my example the result should be 180 degrees (that's what Im trying to get)

Comment: I've found another problem. Now you get numbers between -1 and 1. Now you got cos_t=1, and arc=0. If you need to get 180, then negate `x`, `y`, and `z`.